# aspnetboilerplate IPerWebRequestDependency dont work

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

`C#`

```
public interface IUserInfoOutput: IPerWebRequestDependency
{
    string Id { get; set; }
    string UserName { get; set; }

    string Job { get; set; }

    string Sex { get; set; }
}

public class UserInfoOutput : IUserInfoOutput, IPerWebRequestDependency
{
    public UserInfoOutput()
    {
        Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    public string Job { get; set; }

    public string Sex { get; set; }
}
```

I dont register IUserInfoOutput explicitly because I know ABP will do it in web Project . However，I found it resovled different instance .
note that us and us2 is different . Is anything wrong with my code?or anything else to do ?

```
 public override async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
       // var cookie = HttpContext.Request.Cookies["BLUserAcct"];

       // var user = await _service.GetUserInfo(cookie);

        var us = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IUserInfoOutput>();

        var us2 = IocManager.Instance.Resolve<IUserInfoOutput>();


        await base.OnActionExecutionAsync(context, next);
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is very difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply [it doesn't work](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking). Please edit your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results. See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for hints on what makes a good explanation. Don't forget to provide a working [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I doubt it works with `IocManager.Instance`. Inject an `IIocResolver` instead.